# How to create multiple configuration in Zerotouch? Configuration need enrollment token. Do we need multiple enrollment tokens for creating config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, android-management-api

Get Method of HardwarePolicy

```
    [HttpGet]
    [CustomAuthorization]
    public IActionResult PolicyManagement(string profileType)
    {
        try
        {
            #region ResellerServiceAccountEMMOAuthCred
            ServiceAccountCredential? credential;
            string fileName = "service_account_key.json";
            string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "ZeroTouchCredJSON", fileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                   .CreateScoped(AndroidManagementService.ScopeConstants.Androidmanagement)
                                     .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            }

            // Create a zero-touch enrollment API service endpoint.
            var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ResourceMsg.EMMAppName
            });
            #endregion
            ViewBag.MyPolicyName = string.Empty;
            dynamic? policyId = null;
            CommonPoliciesDto dto = new();
            CommonPoliciesDto cpDto = new();
            bool jFlag = false;
            dynamic enterpriseNameFormat = "";
            //fetch two profile types (Fully Manged & Work)
            dto.ProfileTypeList = _iAdminMapper.GetProfileTypeList();
            //fetch LoggedIn user info
            var loggedInUserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoggedInUserName");
            var loggedInUserId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoggedInUserId");

            //fetch enterprises based on loggedInUser
            var enterprisesRes = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x => x.AdminIdentityId == loggedInUserId).FirstOrDefault();

            //get enterprise data based on loggedIn user google account
            var enterpriseDatax = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x => x.CustomerGoogleAccountId == enterprisesRes.CustomerGoogleAccountId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (enterpriseDatax != null)
            {
                //bind myEnterpriseId in view page
                ViewBag.MyEnterpriseeId = enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId;

                //DeviceList
                //dto.DeviceList = _iAdminMapper.GetDropDevicesList(enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId);

                enterpriseNameFormat = string.Format("enterprises/{0}", enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId);

                //Fetch Current PolicyName
                var myPolicyDatax = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId && x.CustomStatus2 == true).FirstOrDefault();
                if(myPolicyDatax != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.MyPolicyName = myPolicyDatax.PolicyName;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.MyPolicyName = ResourceMsg.DefaultPolicy;
                }

                //fetch policy info based on enterpriseId and profileType
                var policyData = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId && x.PolicyProfileType == profileType && x.PolicyType == ResourceMsg.Default).FirstOrDefault();
                if (policyData != null)
                {
                    policyId = policyData.PolicyId;

                    //managedplaystore
                    List<string> featuresList = new()
                    {
                        ResourceMsg.PLAY_SEARCH
                    };

                    //create web token for managed Google Play web UI; need reseller creds to generated token
                    var ParentFrameUrl = _iConfiguration.GetValue<string>("AppSetting:ParentFrameUrl");
                    WebToken webTokenInfo = service.Enterprises.WebTokens.Create(new DemoWebToken()
                                            .SetParentFrameUrl(ParentFrameUrl)
                                            .SetEnabledFeatures(featuresList), enterpriseNameFormat)
                                            .Execute();
                    var webToken = webTokenInfo.Value;
                    TempData["WebToken"] = webToken;

                    //hardwaresettings
                    var result = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.PolicyId == policyId && x.PolicyType == ResourceMsg.Default).FirstOrDefault();

                    //applicationsettings | based on profileType
                    var resAppmodel = _iEmmMapper.GetApplicationPolicies().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault(x => x.PolicyId == policyId);

                    //devicesettings
                    var resDevicemodel = _iEmmMapper.GetDevicePolicies().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (profileType != null)
                    {
                        //If Managed Profile then perform on all settings
                        if (profileType == ResourceMsg.FullyManged)
                        {
                            if (result != null)
                            {
                                
                            }
                            if (resAppmodel != null)
                            {
                                
                            }
                            if (resDevicemodel != null)
                            {
                                
                            }
                            //prepare commonpolicies vmodel to send to view
                            dto = new()
                            {
                                EnterpriseName = enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseNameRequested,
                                //populate policyNameList
                                //EnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetActiveEnterprisesDropList(),

                                //populate enterprise list
                                EnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetActiveEnterprisesDropList(),

                                //common policies
                                ProfileTypeList = _iAdminMapper.GetProfileTypeList(),
                                ProfileType = profileType,

                                //bindMyEnterpriseId in view
                                MyEnterpriseId = enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId,

                                //hardware settings
                                DupWifiConfigDisabled = cpDto.DupWifiConfigDisabled,
                                DupMobileNetworksConfigDisabled = cpDto.DupMobileNetworksConfigDisabled,
                                DupBluetoothDisabled = cpDto.DupBluetoothDisabled,
                                DupUsbFileTransferDisabled = cpDto.DupUsbFileTransferDisabled,
                                MaximumTimeToLock = cpDto.MaximumTimeToLock,
                                AdjustVolumeDisabled = result != null ? result.AdjustVolumeDisabled : false,
                                ScreenCaptureDisabled = result != null ? result.ScreenCaptureDisabled : false,
                                StatusBarDisabled = result != null ? result.StatusBarDisabled : false,
                                BluetoothContactSharingDisabled = result != null ? result.BluetoothContactSharingDisabled : false,
                                ShareLocationDisabled = result != null ? result.ShareLocationDisabled : false,
                                WifiConfigDisabled = result != null ? result.WifiConfigDisabled : false,
                                MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = result != null ? result.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled : false,
                                AutoDateAndTimeZone = result != null ? result.AutoDateAndTimeZone : ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_UNSPECIFIED,
                                KeyguardDisabled = result != null ? result.KeyguardDisabled : false,
                                CameraDisabled = result != null ? result.CameraDisabled : false,

                                //app settings
                                ApplicationName = cpDto.ApplicationName ?? string.Empty,
                                AppPackageName = cpDto.AppPackageName ?? string.Empty,
                                DupInstallType = cpDto.DupInstallType,
                                DupDefaultPermissionPolicy = cpDto.DupDefaultPermissionPolicy,
                                PackageList = _iEmmMapper.GetApplicationsList(),

                                //device mode settings
                                KioskMode = cpDto.KioskMode,
                                AppPolicyName = "",
                                PackageName = resDevicemodel != null? resDevicemodel.PackageName: "",
                                PackageId = cpDto.PackageId,
                                DupLockPowerButton = cpDto.DupLockPowerButton,
                                StatusBar = cpDto.StatusBar,
                                DupDisableDeviceSettings = cpDto.DupDisableDeviceSettings,
                                SystemNavigation = cpDto.SystemNavigation != null ? cpDto.SystemNavigation : ResourceMsg.SYSTEM_NAVIGATION_UNSPECIFIED,
                                DupEnableSystemErrorWarnings = cpDto.DupEnableSystemErrorWarnings,
                                IsDeleted = resDevicemodel != null ? resDevicemodel.IsDeleted: true,
                                //fetch defaultConfiguration status to show createConfiguration button when status is true
                                IsDefaultConfigurationSet = enterpriseDatax.IsDefaultConfigurationSet,
                                DeviceList = _iAdminMapper.GetDropDevicesList(enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId)

                        };
                            if (jFlag)
                            {
                                //when profile dropdown changed
                                return Json(dto);
                            }
                           // TempData["PolicyApplied"] = TempData["PolicyApplied"];
                            return View(dto);
                        }

                        //If work Profile then perform on hardware and apps settings
                        if (profileType == ResourceMsg.Work)
                        {
                            if (result != null)
                            {
                                
                            }
                            if (resAppmodel != null)
                            {
                                
                            }
                            //prepare commonpolicies vmodel to send to view
                            dto = new()
                            {
                                EnterpriseName = enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseNameRequested,

                                //hardware settings
                                DupWifiConfigDisabled = cpDto.DupWifiConfigDisabled,
                                DupMobileNetworksConfigDisabled = cpDto.DupMobileNetworksConfigDisabled,
                                DupBluetoothDisabled = cpDto.DupBluetoothDisabled,
                                DupUsbFileTransferDisabled = cpDto.DupUsbFileTransferDisabled,
                                MaximumTimeToLock = cpDto.MaximumTimeToLock,
                                AdjustVolumeDisabled = result != null ? result.AdjustVolumeDisabled : false,
                                ScreenCaptureDisabled = result != null ? result.ScreenCaptureDisabled : false,
                                StatusBarDisabled = result != null ? result.StatusBarDisabled : false,
                                BluetoothContactSharingDisabled = result != null ? result.BluetoothContactSharingDisabled : false,
                                ShareLocationDisabled = result != null ? result.ShareLocationDisabled : false,
                                WifiConfigDisabled = result != null ? result.WifiConfigDisabled : false,
                                MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = result != null ? result.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled : false,
                                AutoDateAndTimeZone = result != null ? result.AutoDateAndTimeZone : ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_UNSPECIFIED,
                                KeyguardDisabled = result != null ? result.KeyguardDisabled : false,
                                CameraDisabled = result != null ? result.CameraDisabled : false,

                                //app settings
                                ApplicationName = cpDto.ApplicationName ?? string.Empty,
                                AppPackageName = cpDto.AppPackageName ?? string.Empty,
                                DupInstallType = cpDto.DupInstallType,
                                DupDefaultPermissionPolicy = cpDto.DupDefaultPermissionPolicy,
                                PackageList = _iEmmMapper.GetApplicationsList(),

                                //common policies
                                EnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetActiveEnterprisesDropList(),

                                ProfileTypeList = _iEmmMapper.GetProfileTypeList(),
                                ProfileType = profileType,

                                //bindMyEnterpriseId in view
                                MyEnterpriseId = enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId,
                                //fetch defaultConfiguration status to show createConfiguration button when status is true
                                IsDefaultConfigurationSet = enterpriseDatax.IsDefaultConfigurationSet,

                                DeviceList = _iAdminMapper.GetDropDevicesList(enterpriseDatax.EnterpriseId)
                            };

                            if (jFlag)
                            {
                                //when profile dropdown changed
                                return Json(dto);
                            }
                            return View(dto);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           // TempData["PolicyApplied"] = TempData["PolicyApplied"];
            return View(dto);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _loggerManager.LogError($"Something went wrong inside CommonPolicies get action: {ex.Message}");
            return View(new CommonPoliciesDto());
        }
    }
```

Post Mehtod
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorization]
public IActionResult PolicyManagement(CommonPoliciesDto commonPolicies)
{
try
{
dynamic PolicyAge = string.Empty;
dynamic policyResponse = string.Empty;
string myPolicyId = string.Empty;
//bind myEnterpriseId in view page
ViewBag.MyEnterpriseeId = commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId;

```
            //fetch UserIdentityId
            var userLoggedId = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x=> x.EnterpriseId == commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId).Select(x => x.AdminIdentityId).FirstOrDefault();
            if(userLoggedId != null)
            {
                commonPolicies.UserIdentityId = userLoggedId;
            }

            #region ResellerServiceAccountEMMOAuthCred
            //read service a/c creds
            ServiceAccountCredential? credential;
            string fileName = "service_account_key.json";
            string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "ZeroTouchCredJSON", fileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                     .CreateScoped(AndroidManagementService.ScopeConstants.Androidmanagement)
                                     .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            }

            // Create a zero-touch enrollment API service endpoint.
            var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ResourceMsg.EMMAppName
            });
            #endregion

            ModelState.Remove("PackageName");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId))
                {
                    #region conditions
                    if (commonPolicies.AutoDateAndTimeZone == ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_ENFORCED)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_ENFORCED;
                    }
                    else if (commonPolicies.AutoDateAndTimeZone == ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_USERCHOICE)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_USERCHOICE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commonPolicies.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_UNSPECIFIED;
                    }
                    //
                    if (commonPolicies.WifiMoblieData == 1)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.WifiConfigDisabled = false;
                        commonPolicies.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = true;
                    }
                    else if (commonPolicies.WifiMoblieData == 2)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = false;
                        commonPolicies.WifiConfigDisabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commonPolicies.WifiConfigDisabled = false;
                        commonPolicies.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = false;
                    }
                    //
                    if (commonPolicies.DupBluetoothDisabled == 1)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.BluetoothDisabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commonPolicies.BluetoothDisabled = true;
                        commonPolicies.BluetoothContactSharingDisabled = true;
                    }
                    if (commonPolicies.DupUsbFileTransferDisabled == 1)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.UsbFileTransferDisabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commonPolicies.UsbFileTransferDisabled = true;
                    }
                    if (commonPolicies.MaximumTimeToLock > 0)
                    {
                        commonPolicies.MaximumTimeToLock *= 60000;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region formingPolicyIdFromPolicyName
                    //form Policy Id
                    string myPolicyName = commonPolicies.PolicyName.Trim();
                    bool flag = false;
                    foreach (var data in myPolicyName.ToCharArray())
                    {
                        if (data == ' ')
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag)
                    {
                        string[] polArr = myPolicyName.Split(' ');
                        foreach (var datax in polArr)
                        {
                            myPolicyId += datax + "_";
                        }
                        myPolicyId = myPolicyId.Remove(myPolicyId.Length - 1, 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(myPolicyId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myPolicyId = myPolicyName;
                        //Console.WriteLine(test);
                    }
                    #endregion

                    var entepriseParent = string.Format("enterprises/{0}", commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId);
                    var policyName = string.Format("{0}/policies/{1}", entepriseParent, myPolicyId);
                    //Check if policy exist on server or not
                    //If policy not exist on server then it thru 404 error
                    try
                    {
                        policyResponse = service.Enterprises.Policies.Get(policyName).Execute();
                    }
                    catch (GoogleApiException gex)
                    {
                        //thru 404 error as this is the new policy for the server
                        PolicyAge = ResourceMsg.New;
                    }
                    if (PolicyAge != ResourceMsg.New)
                    {
                        //Policy exist on server
                        PolicyAge = ResourceMsg.Existing;
                    }


                    //condition for add policy
                    if (commonPolicies.ActionType != ResourceMsg.update)
                    {
                        //check if the policyId exist in both database and active in server
                        var IsPolicyExistOnDB = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.PolicyName.ToUpper() == commonPolicies.PolicyName.ToUpper().Trim() && x.PolicyId == myPolicyId && x.EnterpriseId == commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId).Any();
                        
                        //If PolicyExistOnDb or PolicyIsNewToServer then only thru policy exist error
                        if(IsPolicyExistOnDB || PolicyAge == ResourceMsg.Existing)
                        {
                            //If Policy Exist on server then can't create a policy again with the same name
                            TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.PolicyNameAlreadyExist;
                            string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
                            _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ResourceMsg.PolicyNameAlreadyExist}");
                            return View(new EnterpriseDto());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //create a new policy in DB without policyId
                            //as PolicyId only generated by the server which need to be created during apply policy
                            //update data to common policies database table
                            commonPolicies.EnterpriseId = commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId;
                            commonPolicies.PolicyId = "";
                            commonPolicies.PolicyName = commonPolicies.PolicyName;
                            commonPolicies.PolicyType = ResourceMsg.Custom;

                            //update into database
                            var result = _iAdminMapper.CreateUpdateHardwarePolicies(commonPolicies);
                            if (result == 0)
                            {
                                TempData["MsgCmnPolicies"] = ResourceMsg.PoliciesCreatedSuccessfully;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //this msg need to be removed
                                if (result == 1)
                                {
                                    TempData["MsgCmnPolicies"] = ResourceMsg.PoliciesUpdatedSuccessfully;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (commonPolicies.ActionType == ResourceMsg.update)
                    {
                        //If the policy Exist on server then update the policy settings on server thru Policies.Patch endpoint
                        if(PolicyAge == ResourceMsg.Existing)
                        {
                            var newpolicyResponse = service.Enterprises.Policies.Patch(ConfigureCommonPolicies(commonPolicies), policyName).Execute();
                            commonPolicies.PolicyId = myPolicyId;
                        }

                        //update policy on local database
                        commonPolicies.EnterpriseId = commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId;
                        commonPolicies.PolicyId = commonPolicies.PolicyId == null? string.Empty: commonPolicies.PolicyId;
                        commonPolicies.PolicyName = commonPolicies.PolicyName;
                        commonPolicies.PolicyType = ResourceMsg.Custom;

                        //update into database
                        var result = _iAdminMapper.CreateUpdateHardwarePolicies(commonPolicies);
                        if (result == 0)
                        {
                            TempData["MsgCmnPolicies"] = ResourceMsg.PoliciesCreatedSuccessfully;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (result == 1)
                            {
                                TempData["MsgCmnPolicies"] = ResourceMsg.PoliciesUpdatedSuccessfully;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.PolicyNameAlreadyExist;
                        string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
                        _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ResourceMsg.PolicyNameAlreadyExist}");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.TryAgainContactTechnicalTeam;
                    string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
                    _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ResourceMsg.EnterpriseIdIsMissing}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.RequiredFieldsAreEmpty;
                string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
                _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ResourceMsg.RequiredFieldsAreEmpty}");
            }

            CommonPoliciesDto dto = new();
            //fetch & bind two profile types (Fully Manged & Work) on view
            dto.ProfileTypeList = _iAdminMapper.GetProfileTypeList();

            var myEnterpriseName = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId == commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId).Select(x => x.EnterpriseNameRequested).FirstOrDefault();

            //DeviceList
            dto.DeviceList = _iAdminMapper.GetDropDevicesList(commonPolicies.MyEnterpriseId);

            dto.EnterpriseName = myEnterpriseName;
            //pass the dto model to view
            return View(dto);
        }
        catch (GoogleApiException gex)
        {
            TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.PolicyNotFoundContactTechnicalTeam;
            string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{gex.Message}");
            return View(new EnterpriseDto());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.TryAgainContactTechnicalTeam;
            string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            _loggerManager.LogError($"{ex.Message}");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the policy

```
        [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorization]
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to apply hardware policy. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult ApplyHardwarePolicy(string rwId, string devarr)
    {
        try
        {
            #region ResellerServiceAccountEMMOAuthCred
            //read service a/c creds
            ServiceAccountCredential? credential;
            string fileName = "service_account_key.json";
            string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "ZeroTouchCredJSON", fileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                     .CreateScoped(AndroidManagementService.ScopeConstants.Androidmanagement)
                                     .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            }

            // Create a zero-touch enrollment API service endpoint.
            var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ResourceMsg.EMMAppName
            });
            #endregion

            string PolicyAge = string.Empty;
            CommonPoliciesDto model = new();
            string myPolicyId = string.Empty;

            string[] devicesArr = devarr.Split('|');
            devicesArr = devicesArr.SkipLast(1).ToArray();

            //fetch policy information based on rowId
            var policyInfo = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(rwId)).FirstOrDefault();
            if(policyInfo != null)
            {
                //initialize model to assign apps into it
                model.ApplicationDtoList = new List<ApplicationsDto>();
                var appModel = new ApplicationsDto();

                //prepare the model from database response to apply the policy on server
                #region conditions
                if (policyInfo.AutoDateAndTimeZone == ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_ENFORCED)
                {
                    model.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_ENFORCED;
                }
                else if (policyInfo.AutoDateAndTimeZone == ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_USERCHOICE)
                {
                    model.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_USERCHOICE;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_UNSPECIFIED;
                }
                //
                if (policyInfo.WifiConfigDisabled == false && policyInfo.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled == false)
                {
                    model.WifiConfigDisabled = false;
                    model.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = false;
                }
                if (policyInfo.WifiConfigDisabled == true)
                {
                    model.WifiConfigDisabled = true;
                    model.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = false;
                }
                else if (policyInfo.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled == true)
                {
                    model.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = true;
                    model.WifiConfigDisabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.WifiConfigDisabled = false;
                    model.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = false;
                }
                //
                if (policyInfo.BluetoothDisabled == false)
                {
                    model.BluetoothDisabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.BluetoothDisabled = true;
                    model.BluetoothContactSharingDisabled = true;
                }
                //
                if (policyInfo.UsbFileTransferDisabled == false)
                {
                    model.UsbFileTransferDisabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.UsbFileTransferDisabled = true;
                }
                //MaximumTimeToLock
                model.MaximumTimeToLock = policyInfo.MaximumTimeToLock;
                //adjustvolume
                model.AdjustVolumeDisabled = policyInfo.AdjustVolumeDisabled;
                //screencapture
                model.ScreenCaptureDisabled = policyInfo.ScreenCaptureDisabled;
                //statusbar
                if(policyInfo.StatusBarDisabled == true)
                {
                    model.StatusBarDisabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.StatusBarDisabled = false;
                }
                //sharelocation
                model.ShareLocationDisabled = policyInfo.ShareLocationDisabled;
                //keyguard
                model.KeyguardDisabled = policyInfo.KeyguardDisabled;
                //camera
                model.CameraDisabled = policyInfo.CameraDisabled;
                #endregion

                #region forming policyId from policyName
                //form Policy Id
                string myPolicyName = policyInfo.PolicyName.Trim();
                bool flag = false;
                foreach (var data in myPolicyName.ToCharArray())
                {
                    if (data == ' ')
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                if (flag)
                {
                    string[] polArr = myPolicyName.Split(' ');
                    foreach (var datax in polArr)
                    {
                        myPolicyId += datax + "_";
                    }
                    myPolicyId = myPolicyId.Remove(myPolicyId.Length - 1, 1);
                    //Console.WriteLine(myPolicyId);
                }
                else
                {
                    myPolicyId = myPolicyName;
                    //Console.WriteLine(test);
                }
                #endregion

                //Apply the selected policy on server
                //check there is an active policy of the enterprise on server
                var entepriseParent = string.Format("enterprises/{0}", policyInfo.EnterpriseId);
                //var policyName = string.Format("{0}/policies/{1}", entepriseParent, myDefaumyPolicyIdltPolicyId);
                var policyName = string.Format("{0}/policies/{1}", entepriseParent, myPolicyId);

                //Check if policy exist on server or not
                //If policy not exist on server then it thru 404 error
                dynamic appList = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                    appList = service.Enterprises.Policies.Get(policyName).Execute();
                }
                catch (GoogleApiException gex)
                {
                    //thru 404 error as this is the new policy for the server
                    PolicyAge = ResourceMsg.New;
                }

                //If policy is not the new policy then the existing policy
                if (PolicyAge == string.Empty)
                {
                    //If there no 404 exeception from server then the policy is the existing server policy
                    PolicyAge = ResourceMsg.Old;
                }

                //devicename
                dynamic deviceNameAPI = string.Empty;

                if (PolicyAge.Equals(ResourceMsg.New))
                {
                    //create a new policy on the server with the formed policyId thru policies.patch endpoint
                    var newpolicyResponse = service.Enterprises.Policies.Patch(ConfigureCommonPolicies(model), policyName).Execute();
                    
                    //loop thru each requested devices
                    foreach (var deviceId in devicesArr)
                    {
                        //form the deviceName API format
                        deviceNameAPI = string.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", entepriseParent, deviceId);

                        //Check device is exist on server or not
                        var deviceResponse = service.Enterprises.Devices.Get(deviceNameAPI).Execute();

                        //This device belongs to EMM Device; Full fledged path
                        //There is also Device class exist for Zerotouch device
                        Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Device device = new Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Device()
                        {
                            //Assign policyId to policyName
                            PolicyName = myPolicyId,
                            State = ResourceMsg.ACTIVE
                        };
                        //Apply the newly created policy on the requested devices thru device.patch endpont
                        var devicePatchResponse = service.Enterprises.Devices.Patch(device, deviceNameAPI).Execute();
                    }

                    //Update the local database with newly applied policy

                }
                else
                {
                    if (PolicyAge.Equals(ResourceMsg.Old))
                    {
                        //No need to create a new policy on server
                        if (appList != null)
                        {
                            //set all hardware policies exist on server

                            //check if app list is null or not
                            if (appList.Applications != null)
                            {
                                //set all application policies exist from server
                                //fetching existing apps from the provided policy
                                foreach (var app in appList.Applications)
                                {
                                    appModel = new ApplicationsDto()
                                    {
                                        PackageName = app.PackageName,
                                        InstallType = app.InstallType,
                                        DefaultPermissionPolicy = app.DefaultPermissionPolicy
                                    };
                                    model.ApplicationDtoList.Add(appModel);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //update the existing policy
                        var newpolicyResponse = service.Enterprises.Policies.Patch(ConfigureCommonPolicies(model), policyName).Execute();

                        //loop thru each requested devices
                        foreach (var deviceId in devicesArr)
                        {
                            //form the deviceName API format
                            deviceNameAPI = string.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", entepriseParent, deviceId);

                            //Check device is exist on server or not
                            var deviceResponse = service.Enterprises.Devices.Get(deviceNameAPI).Execute();

                            //This device belongs to EMM Device; Full fledged path
                            //There is also Device class exist for Zerotouch device
                            Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Device device = new Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Device()
                            {
                                //Assign policyId to policyName
                                PolicyName = myPolicyId,
                                State = ResourceMsg.ACTIVE
                            };
                            //Apply the newly created policy on the requested devices thru device.patch endpont
                            var devicePatchResponse = service.Enterprises.Devices.Patch(device, deviceNameAPI).Execute();
                        }
                    }
                }
                model.EnterpriseId = policyInfo.EnterpriseId;
                model.PolicyName = policyInfo.PolicyName;
                model.PolicyId = myPolicyId;
                model.PolicyNameApiFormat = policyName;
                model.Custom1 = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();//PolicyAppliedDate
                model.CustomStatus1 = true; //PolicyAppliedOnServerStatus
                //model.CustomStatus2 = true; //IsThisCurrentPolicy

                //update the policyInfo on local database
                var result = _iAdminMapper.CreateUpdateHardwarePolicies(model);
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    //update the IsThisCurrentAppliedPolicy = customstatus2 to false for rest policies under the same policyId
                    //var res = _iAdminMapper.UpdateHardwarePoliciesStatus(model);
                    TempData["PolicyApplied"] = ResourceMsg.PoliciesAppliedSuccessfully;
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["PolicyApplied"] = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam;
                string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
                _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ResourceMsg.PolicyNotFound}");
                return Json(new {success = false,message= ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam });
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, message = TempData["PolicyApplied"] });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ex.Message}");
            TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam;
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what this is supposed to be. Did this solve your problem? If so, you should only post one answer. Or is this intended to provide additional context for your question? If so, it should be an edit to your original question. When you post answers to your own questions, that tells the community that you've solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Method for Delete Policy

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DeleteHardwarePolicy(string rwId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rwId != null)
            {
                #region ResellerServiceAccountEMMOAuthCred
                //read service a/c creds
                ServiceAccountCredential? credential;
                string fileName = "service_account_key.json";
                string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "ZeroTouchCredJSON", fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                         .CreateScoped(AndroidManagementService.ScopeConstants.Androidmanagement)
                                         .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
                }

                // Create a zero-touch enrollment API service endpoint.
                var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ResourceMsg.EMMAppName
                });
                #endregion

                //Fetch enterpriseId based on deviceId where device is active
                var policiesInfo = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(rwId) && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();
                if (policiesInfo != null)
                {
                    //Fetch Default Policy
                    var defaultPolicyId = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId == policiesInfo.EnterpriseId && x.PolicyProfileType == policiesInfo.PolicyProfileType && x.PolicyType == ResourceMsg.Default).Select(x=> x.PolicyId).FirstOrDefault();

                    //If policy is active policy for any devices then after deleting the sever will be updated with default policy
                    var entepriseParent = string.Format("enterprises/{0}", policiesInfo.EnterpriseId);

                    //Fetch DeviceList with ongoing deleted policy
                    //var DevicesList = service.Enterprises.Devices.List(entepriseParent);
                    var deviceList = _iEmmMapper.GetDevices().Where(x => x.PolicyId == policiesInfo.PolicyId && x.IsActive).ToList();
                    if(deviceList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //apply all devices with default policy
                        foreach(var device in deviceList)
                        {
                            var deviceNameAPI = string.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", entepriseParent, device.DeviceId);
                            //Apply policy on device
                            Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Device deviceBody = new Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Device()
                            {
                                //Assign policyId to policyName
                                PolicyName = defaultPolicyId,
                                State = ResourceMsg.ACTIVE
                            };
                            //Apply the newly created policy on the requested devices thru device.patch endpont
                            var devicePatchResponse = service.Enterprises.Devices.Patch(deviceBody, deviceNameAPI).Execute();
                        }
                    }
                        
                    //var policyName = string.Format("{0}/policies/{1}", entepriseParent, policiesInfo.PolicyId);

                    //var policyResponse = service.Enterprises.Policies.Get(policyName).Execute();
                    //if(policyResponse != null)
                    //{
                    //    //If policy exist on server then set default hardware policy
                    //    var appliedPolicyData = service.Enterprises.Policies.Patch(DefaultHardwarePolicies(policiesInfo.PolicyId), policyName).Execute();
                    //}
                    
                    //soft delete policy from local database
                    var result = _iAdminMapper.SoftDeletePolicy(Convert.ToInt32(rwId));
                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        TempData["MsgCmnPolicies"] = ResourceMsg.DeleteMsg;
                        return RedirectToAction("PolicyManagement", "Admin");
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("PolicyManagement", "Admin");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("PolicyManagement", "Admin");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ex.Message}");
            return RedirectToAction("PolicyManagement", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what this is supposed to be. Did this solve your problem? If so, you should only post one answer. Or is this intended to provide additional context for your question? If so, it should be an edit to your original question. When you post answers to your own questions, that tells the community that you've solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

This method for get policy h/w policy

```
        [HttpGet]
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to return hardware policies based on enterprise Id in json format.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enterpriseId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult GetjHardwarePolicies(string enterpriseId)
    {
        try
        {
            IList<CommonPoliciesDto> hardwarePoliciesList = new List<CommonPoliciesDto>();
            List<SelectListItem> deviceDropList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem hardwarePoliciy = new();
            //fetch enterprise name
            var enterpriseName = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x=> x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId).Select(x=> x.EnterpriseNameRequested).FirstOrDefault();

            //fetch devices based on enterprise
            var deviceList = _iEmmMapper.GetDevices().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && x.IsActive).ToList();
            if(deviceList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var device in deviceList)
                {
                    hardwarePoliciy = new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = device.Model,
                        Value = device.DeviceId
                    };
                    deviceDropList.Add(hardwarePoliciy);
                };
            }
            
            if (enterpriseId != null)
            {
                //fetch list of custom hardware policies based on enterprise
                var hardwarePoliciesListResponse = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.EnterpriseId.Equals(enterpriseId) && x.PolicyType == ResourceMsg.Custom && x.IsActive);
                foreach (var policy in hardwarePoliciesListResponse)
                {
                    policy.EnterpriseName = enterpriseName;
                    policy.DeviceList.AddRange(deviceDropList);
                    hardwarePoliciesList.Add(policy);
                }
            }

            //List<SelectListItem> countries = this.Context.Customers.Where(x => x.Country != null)
            //.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            //{
            //    Text = x.Country,
            //    Value = x.Country
            //}).Distinct().ToList();

            return new JsonResult(hardwarePoliciesList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ex.Message}");
            return RedirectToAction("PolicyManagement", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what this is supposed to be. Did this solve your problem? If so, you should only post one answer. Or is this intended to provide additional context for your question? If so, it should be an edit to your original question. When you post answers to your own questions, that tells the community that you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This method is used for edit policy

```
        [HttpGet]
    /// <summary>
    /// This method used to Edit Hardware Setting modal by Id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public JsonResult jEditHardwareSettings(int id)
    {
        CommonPoliciesDto commonModel = new() { Id = id };
        var responseHardwareModel = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (responseHardwareModel != null)
        {
            #region Hardware Settings from database
            //PolicyName
            commonModel.PolicyName = responseHardwareModel.PolicyName;
            //ProfileType
            commonModel.PolicyProfileType = responseHardwareModel.PolicyProfileType;
            //Blutooth
            if (responseHardwareModel.BluetoothDisabled == false)
            {
                commonModel.DupBluetoothDisabled = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                commonModel.DupBluetoothDisabled = 0;
            }
            //USB
            if (responseHardwareModel.UsbFileTransferDisabled == false)
            {
                commonModel.DupUsbFileTransferDisabled = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                commonModel.DupUsbFileTransferDisabled = 0;
            }
            //Wifi
            if (responseHardwareModel.WifiConfigDisabled == false)
            {
                //enabled
                commonModel.DupWifiConfigDisabled = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //disabled
                commonModel.DupWifiConfigDisabled = 0;
            }
            //MobileData
            if (responseHardwareModel.MobileNetworksConfigDisabled == false)
            {
                commonModel.DupMobileNetworksConfigDisabled = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                commonModel.DupMobileNetworksConfigDisabled = 0;
            }
            //ScreenLockTime
            if (responseHardwareModel.MaximumTimeToLock > 0)
            {
                commonModel.MaximumTimeToLock = responseHardwareModel.MaximumTimeToLock / 60000;
            }
            //LockVolume
            commonModel.AdjustVolumeDisabled = responseHardwareModel.AdjustVolumeDisabled;
            //ManageTimeZone
            if (responseHardwareModel.AutoDateAndTimeZone == ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_ENFORCED)
            {
                commonModel.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_ENFORCED;
            }
            else if (responseHardwareModel.AutoDateAndTimeZone == ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_USERCHOICE)
            {
                commonModel.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_USERCHOICE;
            }
            else
            {
                commonModel.AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_UNSPECIFIED;
            }
            //ScreenCapture
            commonModel.ScreenCaptureDisabled = responseHardwareModel.ScreenCaptureDisabled;
            //StatusBar
            commonModel.StatusBarDisabled = responseHardwareModel.StatusBarDisabled;
            //BlutoothContactSharing
            commonModel.BluetoothContactSharingDisabled = responseHardwareModel.BluetoothContactSharingDisabled;
            //GPS
            commonModel.ShareLocationDisabled = responseHardwareModel.ShareLocationDisabled;
            //Keyguard
            commonModel.KeyguardDisabled = responseHardwareModel.KeyguardDisabled;
            //Camera
            commonModel.CameraDisabled = responseHardwareModel.CameraDisabled;
            #endregion

        }

        return Json(commonModel);
    }
```